# c# Edit text in php file

Tags: c#

I have got a php file filled with variables, a variable looks like this:

```
$lang['ClientMain.!success.client_updated'] = 'Your account information has been successfully updated.';
```

Now I would like to use the google API to translate this text to another language, I know how to use the google API the problem that I have is that I don't know how to get the 'Your account information has been successfully updated.' and replace it with the translated string.

I have found a lot of examples on how to open a file and replace the text but I have to select the string, translate it and replace it, I don't want to modify the variable name and the line position.

I hope someone here can help me.

Kind regards,
Piet

Answer (score 0):

You have to create new output file when all your operation is end. Example is working fine:

```
public static void ReplaceTextByKeyword(string inputPath, string outputPath, string keyword, string replaceText)
    {
        string line;
        string searchText = string.Empty;

        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(inputPath);

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains(keyword))
            {
                searchText = line.Split(new string[] { "=" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]
                    .Split(';')[0]
                    .Replace("'", "")
                    .Trim();
                break;
            }
        }

        file.Close();


        var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(inputPath);
        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();

        content = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(content, searchText, replaceText);

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputPath);
        writer.Write(content);
        writer.Close();
    }
```

You can use this like:

```
ReplaceTextByKeyword(@"c:\test\input.txt", @"c:\test\output.txt", "ClientMain.!success.client_updated", "replaceText");
```